# Dynamic width ListViewItem with Animation wpf

Tags: wpf, listviewitem

Can someone tell me how I can make dynamic width ListViewItem elements (here I have buttons). I`ve been trying for a few days and am not coming out... On the film I tried to show what I mean..
https://youtu.be/aR5QSLPoRps

Comment: Please, summarize here in the post your code instead of posting a link with video

Comment: Ok then here is code c# [code c#] https://pastebin.com/hKy4WE7L and here code [xaml] https://pastebin.com/DnkckAtP